# We don't get any images in DXA 2.2 Example site. How are images expected to be published?

Tags: dxa, web8.5, dxa-net, dxa2.2

We are running SDL Web 8.5 and are now trying to install DXA 2.2.
We have followed the installation instruction on SDL Documentation Center regarding Installing DXA for SDL Tridion Sites (hopefully).
We are installing in a DV-environment where we have CMS and Publisher on one server. We have Microservices for deploy and delivery on another windows server. On this server (staging) we have installed an IIS web site DXA Staging containing the DXA .Net Example Site.

When accessing the published out DXA Example Site we don't get any images. I can see when using developer toolbar that there are requests for images, like this one …/media/blueprint_tcm91-90292_w320_h198_n.jpg but they all respond with status 404.

If I look into broker database they don't exist there either. When looking at page templates and component templates I can't see any specific TBBs for publishing images. How are images expected to be published in DXA 2.2?

Images are configured to be stored in broker database and I have tested that to be working.

Comment: You can check you BinaryData folder just to make sure that images are getting downloaded properly. If it is not getting downloaded then you can add the DXA framework code into your project and debug it further.

Comment: I tried to add a publish binary tbb we use in non DXA publications and modify that slightly to generate a filename like the one the example site expects. If I do that they end up in the BinaryData folder. That's why I think something is missing in the publishing process...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I resolved another [issue](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/20669/dxa-example-site-all-links-result-in-no-matching-localization-found-for-url) this problem was resolved as well.
It seams my images was published all the time in original format. But when I saw that the image variants was missing in the website I thought the renditions should be created by TBBs at publishing time. Now I believe they are generated at runtime. For some reason they couldn't be generated due to errors in my topology setup. After fixing that (PublicationMappings) images are generated correctly by the website and end up in BinaryData folder.

Answer (score 2):

Standard DXA TBBs do publish binaries (you can check in Template Builder, in the CME preview or by intercepting a Transport Package).

However, DXA assumes that your Deployer is configured to deploy binaries to the CD Content Store (aka Broker Database). If you say you don’t see anything in the DB, I guess that is your problem.